# Is there a way to shrink pictures in questions and answers?

Tags: support, markdown

When I add pictures to questions or answers, they're often way too large. Is there a way to make them smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post):

> Where the original might be something as obscene as this:
>
> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBb.jpg
> ```
>
> Slip your hand in with `m` or `s` before the file extension like so:
>
> #### Medium:
>
> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBbm.jpg
> ```
>
> #### Smaller:
>
> ```
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBbs.jpg
> ```
>
> You can whack in good ol' HTML for that and force client-side resize:
>
> ```
> <img src="http://example.com/path-to-ghosts.jpg" width="100" height="100">
> ```
>
> But, it's up to you to work out what a good set of resize dimensions
> will be.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!